# Open STF with Bitrise gives Could not get device serials, error:

Tags: mobile, build, automation, bitrise

I added Open STF to Bitrise workflow and gives the following error message while building

```
Could not get device serials, error: [Get http://x.x.x.x:portno/#%21/devices/api/v1/devices: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)] .
```

I have given STF_URL in build step-> Copied the URL in Open STF after log in into the dashboard and pasted the URL in STF_URL parameter in workflow step . 
API token -> Copy pasted the API token from Open STF dashboard .

Answer (score 0):

`Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers` 
Looks like slow internet connection on STF server side.

Could you duration time of that request using curl? e.g. using script step having this body:

`time curl -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-TOKEN-HERE" https://YOUR-HOST-HERE/api/v1/devices`